# Re-create Terraform state file

Tags: terraform

Let me start off by saying I am fairly new to Git...which is what led to this mistake.  I had a lab deployment that I was controlling with a Git repo.  I had my state files in the .gitignore.  I had to do a reset on the local clone I was working from and ran the **git clean -df** not really realizing that it was going to delete my state files...which it did.  The resources are deployed and they are all defined in the the tf files...is there any way to quickly rebuild the state files without making any changes?

Comment: Depends on what you created but you can use `terraform import` to import most resources in the AWS provider at least. There's not an easy way to automate it though. What's most important is that you start storing your state remotely using the remote backends available to you so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yeah, I do that for deployments I am working on with other people but I guess I will start doing it for all of my deployments.  Seems like it will be faster to just manually destroy the resources and then recreate using Terraform.

Comment: Yeah if you don't care about them then that's the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Is this with AWS?